# what do 形 and 便 mean and how can they combine to make the meaning "situation"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word

The Chinese word of 형편 (situation) in Korean is 形便.
Can anyone explain what 形 and 便 mean and how can they combine to make the meaning "situation"?

Comment: "Situation" in Chinese is 形势

Comment: Are you sure you don’t want to ask this at Korean StackExchange?

Comment: Okay, I was thinking this's more related to Chinese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at [MoE](https://www.moedict.tw/%E5%BD%A2%E4%BE%BF)'s definition of 形便, we get:

> 形容地理形勢優良便利。

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=zh-CN&tl=en&text=%E5%9C%B0%E7%90%86%E5%BD%A2%E5%8B%A2%E5%84%AA%E8%89%AF%E4%BE%BF%E5%88%A9) tell us this means:

> Geographical situation is good and convenient

Basically you can think of 形便 as a mix of 形势 (situation) and 便利 (convenient).

---

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%BD%A2%E4%BE%BF) also gives two English definitions:

> **Noun**
>   advantages offered by terrain
>
> **Adjective**
>   convenient (because of the location)

---

So is "situation" in there? Yeah, but it's buried in 形.